# using grep with sed

Tags: sed, grep

trying to find all files with this text "david_now" and replace with this "david_old"

`grep -r "david_now" | sed -i 's"david_now"david_old"g`'

It fails on some files and stops  example:

```
sed no input files
BRF/Test_page.mujebr3.brf: binary file matches
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the output of grep -- a list of files -- as input to sed. If you want sed to actually operate on those files, you'll need to use the `xargs` command, as in:

```
grep -rl "david_now" | xargs sed -i 's"david_now"david_old"g'
```

This will mostly work, although if you have filenames that contain whitespace you'll need to modify grep to use a NUL seperator between filenames:

```
grep -rlZ "david_now" | xargs -0 sed -i 's"david_now"david_old"g'
```